# AngularJS ngResource and IE9 issue: response.data is undefined in the error callback function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource, angularjs-http

**ISSUE**: In IE9, when I call $resource.save, I get **undefined** on `response.data` inside the error callback function. In chrome, `response.data` has the "errors" JSON object returned from the server.

Here is the $resource call:

    `TicketResource.save(inputParams, function (data) {
        //the data object is same on both browsers
    }, function (response) {//called when server returns status 422
        //IE9: response.data is undefined
        //Chrome: response.data contains the server returned JSON object
    });`

In IE9 developer tools, "statusText" on the response object has this error

    `statusText: "IOError [IOErrorEvent type=\"ioError\" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text=\"Error #: [IOErrorEvent type=\"ioError\" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text=\"Error #2032"`

Note: In my app, no custom responseInterceptors are defined on $httpProvider

Appreciate any inputs on this issue!

Comment: Does it work the first time around, but fail on subsequent saves?

Comment: Nope, it does not work the first time around. I failed to mention that I am sending multi-part form data using angular-file-upload directive

Comment: Are you using the FileAPI module?  Apparently angular-file-upload [acts up with older browsers](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload#old_browsers) like IE9.  [This ticket](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload/issues/182) may also help.

Comment: Yes, I am using FileAPI which uses Flash to upload the files. There is an open ticket which states that Flash does not return the error response sent from the server.